# how to check whether gridview's row is selected or not in c#.net windows application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, gridview

I want to know how to check whether a gridview's row got selected or not.
I am working on windows application.

I want to put a if condition ie if a particular row gets selected then fill the textbox with the correspoding cell value.

I am just not getting the way how to give the condition in the if clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handle the [DataGridView.SelectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged.aspx) event. Use the [DataGridView.SelectedRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows.aspx) property to get the selected rows collection.

```
private void dataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Update the text of TextBox controls.
    textBox1.Text = dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    textBox2.Text = dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    ....
}
```

Comment: i worked out this code but i am geting error:"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.Parameter name: index"  Here is the code that i have written:              private void dbGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
  {
 txtWorkStation.Text = dbGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();             
            txtVerNo.Text = dbGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            txtBrokerId.Text = dbGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString(); -----                      
}

Comment: @Sonali: I believe you have no selected rows here. Try to check the value of the dbGridView.SelectedRows.Count ...

Comment: @Sonali: I'll appreciate if you thanked me by accepting the most appropriate answer ..

Answer (score 0):

Check [DataGridViewRow.Selected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.selected.aspx) property.

```
if (dataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Selected)
{
    // Do something ..
}
```

Comment: i just want to fill the textboxes whenever a particular row gets selected with the grid values. i want the if condition where i am checking whether the grid views row is selected or not if selected then fill the textbox with the corresponding values of grid

Comment: hello! there r at least 20 textboxes to b filled. so how can i fill the textboxes when the gird view is selected

Answer (score 0):

Check the selected property of `DataGridViewRow`, it returns `true` for selected else `false`.

```
bool isSelected = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected;
```

Comment: i just want to fill the textbox when particular row is selected.here is the code that i have written but not executing                                                   if(dbGridView.Rows[rowindex].Selected) { txtWorkStation.Text = dbGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString(); txtVerNo.Text = dbGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString(); -------}     so how can i get the textboxes filled when proper row gets selected

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the SelectionChanged event of the control and iterate through each selected row if multi-selection is enabled or just the first one if single-row selection only.

```
private void MyGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      for (int i = 0; i < MyGridView.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
      {
          MyTextBox.Text = MyGridView.SelectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(); //assuming column 0 is the cell you're looking for

          // do your other stuff
      }
}
```

More information can be found on the [SelectedRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows.aspx) property.